# Display timout resets to 15 seconds occasionally

Tags: 2.2-froyo, settings, samsung-galaxy-tab, screen

Hi on my SGT the display timout resets to 15 seconds occasionally. I can't reproduce this behavior but it seems that this reset happens at every reboot at least and sometimes when connecting/disconnecting the powersupply.

Can someone tell me how to have this setting fixed again at 10 minutes?

If it helps, the phone is rooted, but I am not sure if this problem occurred already before root. At least unrooting did not help. Also I have my battery saving software let the settings back to default and then deinstalled, did not help either.

Comment: I would make nandroid backup, full titanium backup, wipe data/cache/battery stats, flash stock ROM and see if the problem manifests on stock. If it does, bother the vendor. If not, I would restore one by one all system apps from Titanium Backup to see where the problem settings is.

Comment: Running software cannot help save battery, apart from underclocking.  Uninstall crapware, turn the brightness down, exit apps when you're done with them, and turn off the radios when you can ... that's about all you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the 'battery saving software' might have caused the issues. Did you experience these issues before installing the app ? There is a couple of ways which might help restore original settings :

- A factory reset might set it right.
- Alternatively if you have a backup of your original firmware you might want to try reflashing your phone after backing up all data.

ps :  The name of the app you were using might help out.

Comment: The Problem is that I tried several of this Apps, but before deinstallation I ever let it set the manipulated settings back to the defaults. The last I used was JuiceDefender, but I dont recal if this Problem was already before. Since the phone is rooted, cant I edit some text-configfile as it would be the way I am used to from linux?

Comment: I can only imagine that one of the apps did not do the setting restore properly (maybe corrupted)