# Every time I reboot the system, it will return the default display sleep time to 15 seconds, how to fix this?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, settings, screen

I'm on Android 4.1.2, in a Motorola Razr D3, and every time the mobile power off, or I reboot it, the default display sleep time will get back to 15 seconds, and I have to set it to 1 minute again, as I want it.

Other configurations like "Language" or "Auto-rotate screen" are not resetting.

In opposite to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11801/display-timout-resets-to-15-seconds-occasionally), I did not installed any battery saver software. Although the SmartActions app comes with the phone, and I enabled the "Low Battery Saver" option which would reduce the bright of the screen when the battery is low, I don't think it should affect the sleep time, even more with full battery. I disabled it to test, and there was no change.

Any idea why it's resetting this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LockerPro app was reseting my screen lock time to 15 seconds.

(the Android system should offer a way to check who is changing the system settings)